# Extract string from labels in xaml to resource files

Tags: silverlight

I can't find any method of extracting string values from xaml (Silverlight) to a resource file. Do I really have to do this manually?

If this is not supported in VS2010, are there any 3rd party tools which offers help on this issue?

Building and maintaining resource files for localization purposes is quite tedious if you have to do this manually.

Comment: I am not aware if any tool like this exists. We are maintaining resx file manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick: http://wpflocalizeaddin.codeplex.com/

Comment: The addin appears to be no longer maintained, supporting only VS2008 and VS2010, but I was able to run this successfully in VS2013 on a WPF project by following its install instructions then editing the version tag of the XamlLocalizerAddin.AddIn file to be 12.0 (you'll note the content of the version tag is the only difference between the VS2008 addin and the VS2010 addin).

Answer (score 0):

XAML is just XML, so you can write an XML parser in a Winforms app to find all the strings.

We did away with the need for the resources using a different technique (based on attached properties):

[Link: *Localisation of Silverlight projects after completion*](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?cat=23)

Comment: I just find it strange that VS2010 does not implement this feature, as it would make it a lot more handy to work with resource files

Comment: Anything new about current versions of VS?
A tool for using VS2013 would be great. Unfortunatly the wpflocalizeadding seems not to be maintained anymore.